# C# ASP.NET browser resize event

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser, event-handling, onresize

I cannot find a resize event for my C# Asp.Net application. I'm trying to do something like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp), but there is no `onresize` event in my `<body runat="server" ..>`.

How do I add a function call on the event of browser resize in my C# ASP.NET application?

Comment: It would have to be implemented in javascript. You could do an ajax call if the code to execute needs to be in C#.

Comment: You says it's a .net application as above we assume it HTML in which case would require the use of JavaScript. Are you able to give more detail as to what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your custom resize handler to the window using JavaScript.  Something like this.

```
<script>
function customResize(){
  //your code
}

function onLoad(){
  window.onresize = customResize;
}
</script>
<body onload="onLoad"></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the below article, which has a jQuery example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cross-browser-window-resize-event-using-javascript-jquery/

Sorry looks like very old thread. I just wanted to have it here, in case someone is still looking for an answer.